# Windows 10: No scrolling on touchpad

Tags: windows-10

I have Toshiba Satellite L650 and I have just yesterday updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Earlier, I could scroll using both one-finger and two-finger scrolling but after the update, I can't. Any help??

Comment: Lots of prefs get reset updating to Win 10 - just see if the touchpad control panel is how you left it.

Comment: Are you scrolling the right direction?  On my machine, scroll direction got flipped after the upgrade.  I had to change it back in settings.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this by saying that I have a Satellite C855-S5194. I had the same issue when I installed the Insider Preview. The synaptic drivers were installed and seemed to be up to date.

**A few things that you can try [that worked for me]:**

> 1.  Check your touchpad settings in Settings>Devices>Mouse and Touchpad. You may have to click *'Additional Mouse Options'* and make sure two fingered scrolling is enabled. 
> 2. Restart your Computer. This generally will fix any issues.
> 3. Check the Toshiba website for an updated Synaptic driver.

Hopefully this will solve it for you!